# Quando usar "ainda melhor", e quando usar "melhor ainda"

Tags: ordem-de-expressões

Tem uma diferença de significado, ou situações onde a gramática dita que dá para usar uma forma só?

Pesquisei no google notícias pelas duas frases para ler exemplos com contexto, e eu não entendi em nenhum exemplo porque se usou um e não se usou o outro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para responder à tua pergunta, peneirei cinco exemplos de "ainda melhor" e cinco  de "melhor ainda" na Internet:

> - E se a teoria da medicina do riso é algo bom, a prática é **ainda melhor**!
> - Agora, se eu conseguisse convencê-lo a se assumir para os pais, talvez ficasse tudo **ainda melhor**.
> - O melhor ficou **ainda melhor** — este é um dos slogans prediletos dos publicitários.
> - Vamos fazer algo **ainda melhor**.
> - Para muitas pessoas, a vida de solteiro/a fica **ainda melhor** com a idade

Em todos os exemplos acima, se invertermos a ordem da locução para "melhor ainda", a frase continua sendo idiomática e retem o seu significado original.

Vejamos agora os exemplos abaixo:

> - Mas podemos fazer algo **melhor ainda**.
> - É óbvio que, se você puder operar a magia em toda a casa, será **melhor ainda**.
> - .....da sensação refrescante e relaxante da água durante o exercício, que se torna **melhor ainda** quanto mais o corpo relaxa.
> - Daquela vez então, era **melhor ainda**, pois ao meu lado — fazendo bem ao meu coração — caminhava a pessoa mais bonita do mundo
> - Durante a noite é **melhor ainda**: além de proporcionar bem-estar,......

Novamente, a ordem dos fatores não altera o produto. Usando "melhor ainda" ou "ainda melhor", o significado é o mesmo.

No entanto, observo que "melhor ainda" quando isolado do restante da frase por vírgula(s), seu uso é idiomático em pt-BR e a inversão, embora gramaticalmente correta, não soa tão bem aos nossos ouvidos.

exemplo:

> - **Melhor ainda**: suas mãos não vão tremer, você não vai precisar segurar anotações e conseguirá...
> - Ou, **melhor ainda**, vou ligar para a empresa do cartão de crédito para cancelá-lo.

Uma procura no Google Books mostrou 498 resultados para "ou, melhor ainda, se" e 127 resultados para "ou, ainda melhor, se".

Já na frase "O melhor ainda está por vir." a inversão não é possível por motivos óbvios.

Comment: Depende da ênfase. "ainda melhor" a ênfase é na atitude de melhorar, na ação de tornar melhor, de fazer se tornar melhor. Usar "melhor ainda" a ênfase está naquilo ser melhor, ser a melhor opção,

Comment: Contribuo que no Rio de Janeiro 'ainda melhor' soa bem aos ouvidos.

Comment: @William  Meu pt-BR é do Rio de Janeiro. Sim, a minha resposta diz que as duas formas estão gramaticamente corretas, significam a mesma coisa, e são de uso corrente. Contudo, "melhor ainda" **quando isolado por vírgulas**, me parece mais frequente e mais idiomático do que "ainda melhor".  Por exemplo "... Melhor ainda, se você puder..."